# On a high level, how would I render a bunch of meshes in react-three-fiber, all of which need to know their position at all times?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

Essentially I need a few dozens (basic) meshes moving around the screen at once, and they all have to know their position at all times. The method I've tried slows down at around 10 or so meshes, and is remarkably slow by 30. On a high level, how would I go about this? Surely it's possible, right?

Comment: [See the code in this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=instanc#webgl_instancing_dynamic)

Comment: 30 is nothing, if that is slow then your means to move them is the problem. other than that, if you're dealing with hundreds of meshes and they're all the same geometry, then instancing will solve it. https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-instanced-colors-forked-h873k